# Updating data in a Dropbox (or Drive) shared file using their API in Java desktop application

Tags: java, database, sqlite, hosting

Can I store a database file on Dropbox or Drive and still update, select, etc.? If so, how can I do that with Java?

I made a desktop Java application that has an SQLite file as its database file and it is working fine. Now I want to make the DB file accessible from two different applications.

I don't have to worry about concurrency issues because one user can write into the file the other can just see what's happening in the DB file from his application

I read in the Appropriate Uses for SQLite that it can do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared DB file can be located on Dropbox file after downloading it on the desktop in both computers and use it as every DB file befor